# Eclipse debugger hits breakpoint but I can't move it

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, selenium

I've used Eclipse for a long time so I'm fairly familiar with the debugger. On my current project we are doing browser automation with Selenium. Recently I've been having an issue where, when debugging, I hit one of my breakpoints and I am unable to step forward or continue - I can only stop. The other step buttons are disabled and grayed out. I'm completely confused as to why this happens (not super familiar with exactly how debugging happens). Once in a while it works but I can't tell why it worked suddenly. After one successful run it goes back to being unresponsive after hitting a break point. I thought it might be a multi-thread issue but I'm just guessing. I tried terminating and removing the running threads but that doesn't seem to help.

Any idea why this is? I'm using Eclipse Java EE IDE Mars 4.5.1.

Comment: You have multiple threads and the stopped thread is not the one with the focus in the Eclipse IDE?

Comment: it's difficult to help you if you don't have a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).  what's the code surrounding the breakpoint?

Comment: My best guess is that you didn't breakpoint but that you paused

Comment: The debugger arrow is white instead of yellow if that helps. I'm confused because in other tests the debugger works just fine.

Comment: Screen shot(s) would help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to focus the correct line in the callstack in Debug view.

*I know this question has been asked some while ago, but I just came across the same issue, and it might potentially help other people in the future.*